# django tastypie create API to patch user details on the basis of username

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am newbie to Tastypie and django and facing some problem related to user update. I have create the UserProfileResource, and defined obj_update method to PATCH user and its profile details. It is working find when I am patching with UserProfile pk i.e.

```
/api/v1/userprofile/1/ --data {"user":{"username":"mac","first_name":"updated_mac"}, "phone":"09534546789"}
```

Now I have two questions to modify this code :
**1. How to update user details one the basis of username provided and not from pk in the URL i.e.**

```
/api/v1/userprofile/ --data {"user":{"username":"mac","first_name":"updated_mac"}, "phone":"09534546789"}
```

**2. While updating the user profile how can I validate that new phone already does not exists in the system ?**

**UserProfileResource**

```
class UserProfileResource(ModelResource):
'''Fetch customer details and all coupons'''
  user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', null=True, full=True)

  class Meta:
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()
    authorization  = DjangoAuthorization()
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)
    resource_name = 'userprofile'
    list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
    detail_allowed_methods = ['patch']
    excludes = ['added_on', 'updated_on']
    include_resource_uri = False
  def obj_update(self, bundle, **kwargs):
    try:
        # if raw password is provided then create hash from it
        raw_password = bundle.data["user"].get('password')
        if raw_password == "":
            raise CustomBadRequest(
                code="key_error",
                message="Blank password is provided.")

        bundle.data["user"]["password"] = make_password(raw_password)
    except KeyError:
        pass

    # check if email, phone already not exists - TODO
    return super(UserProfileResource, self).obj_update(bundle, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You can override `obj_create`, get the id of that user by email, then return `obj_update`

Comment: @dan-klasson While I am overriding obj_create and returning obj_update I am getting MultipleObjectsReturned  "More than 'User' matched Error. Might be because update obj_update expects the detail uri , but I am using list uri. How to handle this with list uri ?

Comment: Do you need it to update multiple users at once?